Add static text in source code (C++) in local functions and retrieving it at program start w/o calling those local functions?
At various places in the C++ source code, in different files, I want to add comments, like:
{
    setError(1); // 1 will be replaced by an unique constant (enum) 
    #ifdef SIMULATOR
    ADD_INFO_FOR_ERROR(1, "some explanation for error 1");
    #endif
}

It should be only used if SIMULATOR is defined and therefore performance will not play any role. The texts should be retrieved in the main() function and printed out or with any other method. At the end I need a spreadsheet. The text should be added in the sourcecode below the use of the functions "setError".
This approach would be possible with gcc by placing the text into a separate section, like:
#define ADD_INFO_FOR_ERROR(INTEGERVALUE, CONSTANTTEXT) \
    static const struct { \
        int index; \
        const char *text; \
    } entry_##INTEGERVALUE __attribute__((section(".my_table_section"), used)) = {INTEGERVALUE, CONSTANTTEXT};

However, this does not work with my simulator system, because retrieving from sections does not work there (Touchgfx simulator). On the productive embedded systems it seems to work.
Are there alternatives or tools to achieve it? I use gcc.
Remark: The use case here is very much simplified, I only want to know if it is technically possible.

Is there any reasons you don't want to invert the problem, essentially store the map of error codes to reasons somewhere centrally, and have the return code in the function return a value in the set of keys?  That is the normal technique.  The actual map and the printing in main() then are the only things that need to be guarded by an #ifdef.

@Chuu: I wanted to have the static reason text near the source code. If the source code will be modified once, the text can be immediately adjusted.

ADD_INFO_FOR_ERROR(1, "some explanation for error 1"); is not a comment. Why do you need to add comments conditionally (they will be removed by the compiler anyway)? And what do you mean by "retrieved in the main() function"? How is your macro with structure definition related to your problem?

The info text  should be only used and printed in the main() if the code is compiled with SIMULATOR/TEST functionality, not on the productive system.

Does main need explanation for an arbitrary error code that could be set but haven't yet; or only for error codes that have actually occurred? Something like this would work for the latter: a global variable of type std::map<int, char*> or similar, with ADD_INFO_FOR_ERROR(code, message) expanding to globalErrorMap[code]=message;.

"1 will be replaced by an unique constant (enum)" The place where those unique constants are defined strikes me as a good place to also provide explanations for them - rather than scattering them all over the codebase. Otherwise, what should happen if two pieces of code set the same error but provide different explanations?

The other obvious question is why you need this in a section of the executable.  There are a bunch of techniques that you can put together with macros and static/constexpr functions to make this available to main().  Which satisfies the requirement of generating a spreadsheet in main().  Unless the requirement to be able to do this with elftools and such is actually a hard requirement.

I want to put the text near the function, in local scope and w/o execution of the code during runtime. How could I use macros and static/constexpr?

@Igor: The error which could be set. It is not an error code but a unique constant which is used only at one place. The handling function divides it into error component, error, error code and another constant in order to being able to find the exact place in the source code where the error situation was detected/generated.
